# Python - Sintaxis (if, else)

Tags: python, condiciones, sintaxis, else

Me gustaría saber cuál es el error de sintaxis que estoy cometiendo, en mi código.
La consola me marca error en el **`else`**, ya intente ponerlo de varias formas pero no encuentro solución, seguramente existe una respuesta que desconozco.
También me gustaría saber sí hay forma de hacer mi código en menos líneas o de otra forma.

```
colores = ["rojo", "verde", "azul"]
color = input("Qué color desea: ").lower()
respuesta = (color in colores)
print(type(respuesta))
if respuesta:
    print(f"Sí tenemos color {color}")
    else:
        print(f"No tenemos el color {color}")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Python es importante la tabulación o los espacios para definir los bloques de código , tu error de sintaxis esta en que el else esta dentro del bloque del if, debes tabular el else para que quede al mismo nivel

```
colores = ["rojo", "verde", "azul"]
color = input("Qué color desea: ").lower()
respuesta = (color in colores)
print(type(respuesta))
if respuesta:
    print(f"Sí tenemos color {color}")
else:
    print(f"No tenemos el color {color}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola el else esta mal identado :).

```
colores = ["rojo", "verde", "azul"]
color = input("Qué color desea: ").lower()

if color in colores:
    print(f"Sí tenemos color {color}")
else:
    print(f"No tenemos el color {color}")
```

Answer (score 1):

en python todo else tiene que tener su respectivo if efectivamente el error de tu programa es que no declaraste el else en el mismo hilo del if ,python lo va a tomar como si ese else no  fuera aparte del if principal
la solucion correcta para esste codigo seria la siguiente tambien te recomiendo que uses la función (str) a si evitarías conflictos con versiones anteriores de python

```
colores = ["rojo", "verde", "azul"]
color = input(str("Qué color desea: ")).lower()
respuesta = (color in colores)
print(type(respuesta))
if respuesta:
    print(f"Sí tenemos color {color}")
else:
    print(f"No tenemos el color {color}")
```

Comment: le estoy dicciendo cual es el error por que pasa el error y como solucionarlo de paso ledi una recomendación de como pude mejorar el codigo